# why does python-sympy need 520MB?

Tags: apt, python, software-installation

I wanted to install sympy so when I typed

```
sudo apt-get install python-sympy
```

I get the following output:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
    dvipng fonts-cabin fonts-comfortaa fonts-droid fonts-freefont-otf
    fonts-gfs-artemisia fonts-gfs-complutum fonts-gfs-didot
    fonts-gfs-neohellenic fonts-gfs-olga fonts-gfs-solomos fonts-inconsolata
    fonts-junicode fonts-lato fonts-linuxlibertine fonts-oflb-asana-math
    fonts-sil-gentium fonts-sil-gentium-basic fonts-stix otf-freefont
    python-sympy texlive-fonts-extra texlive-fonts-extra-doc texlive-xetex
Need to get 228 MB of archives.
After this operation, 524 MB of additional disk space will be used.
```

Do I need all these fonts? I think that is what is increasing the size so much. If I don't need them how do I install python-sympy without the fonts.

As far as I can tell this is the page for the package [python-sympy](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/python-sympy) and it doesn't seem to depend / recommend the packages above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

texlive-fonts-extra pulls in all the other fonts. While I'm not familiar with sympy, I looked at its webpage and will note that when I use to write papers in college, the largest consumer of disk space was all the fonts necessary for producing high quality text with mathematical symbols.

Comment: It was even worse for me. “ 2,381 MB of additional disk space will be used”!

Answer (score 3):

The font dependencies are only recommended (dependencies of `texlive-fonts-extra`). You can install `sympy` without these using the `--no-install-recommends` option:

```
sudo apt-get install python-sympy --no-install-recommends
```